# Is there a fast way to compute the lowest eigenvalue of this symmetric PD matrix in this specific scenario?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider

$$C = A^H D A + M$$

where

- $A$ is a $m \times m$ unitary matrix.
- $D$ is a $m \times m$ diagonal matrix with entries either $0$ or $1$. 
  The number of $1$'s is $n \ll m$.
- $M$ is a $m \times m$ diagonal matrix with all real non-negative entries, with atleast one positive entry.

It is known that $C$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Is there a fast way to compute the lowest eigenvalue (need not compute the eigenvector) of $C$?

Especially given $n \ll m$ and $m$ being very large I cannot afford to compute all $m$ eigenvalues. Also I would like to avoid storing a  $m \times m$  matrix in memory if possible.

PS : Inverse iteration, or Power iteration methods are generic and I don't find them taking any advantage of this specific scenario. So is Rayleigh Quotient method. Appreciate some leads for an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Is there something special about the unitary matrix $A$? Otherwise already the input needs $O(m^2)$ for storing.

Comment: @user35593 : look at D. I dont need to store entire A due to D.

Comment: @user35593 : yes I have a closed form expression/formula to generate entries of A.

Comment: If you also have a fast algorithm for the matrix multiplication an iterative method (e.g. power or inverse) could make use of it.

Comment: @user35593 : matrices A and M are fixed constants, D is the input to the algorithm. D is the one that varies

Comment: some approach : $B = A^H D A $ is a $m\times m$ symmetric PSD with top $n$ eigen values equal to $1$ and the remaining $(m-n)$ being zero. $n<<m$